# How to test if packet is sent correct?

Tags: c++, python, testing, networking

In my app i sent packet by **raw socket** to another computer than get packet back and write the return packet to another computer by raw socket. 
My app is c++ application run on Ubuntu work with nfqueue.

I want to test sent packets for both computer1 and computer2 in order to check if they are as expected.
I need to write an automation test that check my program, this automation test need to listen to the eth load the sent packets and check if they are as expected (ip,ports, payload).

I am looking for a simple way (tool (with simple API), code) to do this.
**I need a simple way to listen (automate) to the eth .**
I preffer that the test will check the sender , but it might be difficult to find an api to listen the eth (i sent via raw socket) , so a suggested API that will check the receivers computers is also good.
The test application can be written in c++, java , python.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want to do, but would something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) work as a testing tool for you?

Comment: I hope that question is clearer now. i need automation test.

Comment: What is the test going to prove? That no corruption occurred during the test? If you want traffic integrity, use a cryptographic signature. Ie. [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Comment: @ Remus Rusanu , the test need to check the packet if they are sent correct . my app build them and sent them to these 2 computers and i need a white box test to see that the packet sent correct.

Comment: Why are you using raw sockets instead of an established protocol like TCP/IP or UDP/IP?  You realize you need to be running as root to create raw sockets, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I operate tcpdump on the reciver coputer and save all packet to file.
I analysis the tcpdump with python and check that packet send as expected in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Auto generate a large list of random packets, give the list to both computers and start sending them and when received, have them checked against the list.  Computer 1 will send and then wait for a reply from computer 2.  Computer 2 will check the packets and then send either a success or failure packet.  Log the results on either computer (doesn't matter) and then you could generate statistics from the log file. Use this method in both directions to test both connections if needed. Should be extremely simple in python.

Or go crazy and use Hamming Codes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code (wiki)
http://lionel.textmalaysia.com/hamming-code-in-python.html (explanation and some code)

Comment: I am looking for a api to capture the sent packets

Comment: well you are definitely doing something wrong then.  Capturing packets should be the easiest part of your job.  Stop using raw sockets unless you have to because you are going to end up in a place you don't want to be.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check if a packet has been sent correctly is by verifying it's integrity on the receiving end.

Comment: how do you suggest to check it (automation). i am willing and want to compromise and on that will check the sent by dumping or listen to the sender eth.

Comment: You could check the formatting, the size, ect. Make sure you use TCP as it is more reliable.

Comment: I am looking for a api to capture the sent packets

Comment: I don't think you will find an api for this. I'm not even sure I understand what your question is now... Where do you want to capture the packets? On the client or server side? If your answer is server, there is absolutely no point in capturing packets that you are sending, because you should know what you're sending in the first place.

Comment: Yeah the question makes no sense to me either.  Oh well, I tried